# Does Django admin support regex url?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I writed something like this:
`url(r'^oog\d{3}/', admin.site.urls)`
But when I open admin site, then visit some model.
It show me the url is 0.0.0.0:8000/oog000/app... and it could not open.

Does re_path support admin.site.urls?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible without diving **deep** into the `AdminSite` object.. and I don't see any real benifit of being able to access the same admin page with `oog001` and `oog002`

I was able to get it to at least run with:

```py
re_path(r'^admin(([0-9]+)/)?', admin_site.urls),
```

But immediately:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin12/

admin.index() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

args looks like:

```
(<WSGIRequest: GET '/admin12/'>, '12/', '12')
```

You can pop off those two 12's and get the index to load, but than any other url in the admin ends up like

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/adminapp1/
```

None of the Model tables work, I presume you've also got to pop the numbers off:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/adminapp1/model1/

ModelAdmin.changelist_view() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

I'd suggest not doing this

Comment: Thanks, I want mange multiple apps in one admin, but they are looks like independent from eachother。（just look）

I use get_queryset() to show different entry for different app(distinguish according to from url), every entry belongs to one app.
url like this:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/app1
http://127.0.0.1:8000/app2

Comment: So I want to find a solution for this. So far I can only change some templates to resolve it. But I am not sure is this Best Practice.

Comment: Django admin is awesome, we maintain many similar CMS project with it. 
But we want it to be look like independent, avoid data pollution.
We use Django admin on production level without any problem. It also work will with vue.js.

We try to rewrite CMS with Springboot，but the status is not very good.
 I am come from China with poor English. Maybe you can feel it. lol..

Comment: When you say `multiple apps` do you mean multiple Django projects?
Because if you mean `multiple apps` inside of a **single** Django project, they already share an admin ex: `127.0.0.1:8000/admin/app1` & `127.0.0.1:8000/admin/app2`
If multiple projects, maybe look into making an `django-admin` project that just imports all other individual projects Databases.
I've never done the multiple databases, but I presume Django's admin works with them. The only pain would be miss-matched models, you'll have to update the main project's model and then the django-admin's

Comment: We used to use multiple databases (same tables and fields) with one app/admin.
Now we want to use one databases with one app/admin.
But we should show different items in change_form, (according to where the user came from，May be browser address)


eg. 
user come from http://127.0.0.1:8000/oog101/model_name, will show items belongs to oog101.
user come from  http://127.0.0.1:8000/oog102/model_name, will show items belongs to oog102.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('articles/2003/', views.special_case_2003),
    re_path(r'^articles/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/$', views.year_archive),
    re_path(r'^articles/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9]{2})/$', views.month_archive),
    re_path(r'^articles/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9]{2})/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.article_detail),
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But I should said, re_path does support something like views.year_archive, but not admin.site.urls.